# get value Kendo NumericTextBoxFor when it is disabled

Tags: kendo-ui

Hi I have the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(e => e.ListPrice)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 80px;height: 15px;font-size: 11px;" })
.Format("{0:c}")
.Enable(false)
.Spinners(false))
```

I set my numeric text value when the use click on the grid:

```
var grid = $("#grd").data("kendoGrid");
var rowSel = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
$('#ListPrice').data('kendoNumericTextBox').value(rowSel.ListPrice);
```

I can see it on the screen.  But when I submit the form, it is always default to null in my model.  However, if I set it enable to true, my model shows the current value.

Can you help me on this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.  I will use @readonly instead:

```
.HtmlAttributes( new { @readonly = "readonly" }))
```